# Долгое обращение к методу

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток.

Имеем два потока: основной и дочерний. В основном потоке происходит некоторая обработка поступаемых данных с помощью метода, дочерний поток получает эти данные и отправляет обрабатываться в основной поток. Во время отправки данных происходит обращение к методу, который производит обработку. Когда происходит первая, самая первая отправка данных и обращение к этому методу, то возникает задержка от 30 до 60 секунд, при чем если проследить по брейк поинтам, то действительно - программа непонятно чем занимается и не сразу обращается к методу. Все последующие обращения к методу происходят без задержек. Метод, к которому идет обращение состоит из 30к строк.

Метод который берет данные из файла и работает в дочернем потоке

```
private void GetBid()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryParam = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<string> dis = new List<string>();
        string lines = "";
        while (Run)
        {
            Status.Text = "Статус: ОЖИДАНИЕ СВЕЧЕЙ";
            if (File.Exists("OnProject\\candles.txt"))
            {
                lines = "";
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("OnProject\\candles.txt"))
                        lines = myReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                catch { }

                if (lines.Length != 0)
                {
                    Status.Text = "Статус: ОБРАБОТКА";
                    File.Delete("OnProject\\candles.txt");
                    string[] ll = lines.Split('#');
                    string[] gg;
                    for (int i = 0; i < ll.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        Status.Text = "Статус: ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ СВЕЧЕЙ";
                        gg = ll[i].Split(';');

                        DictionaryParam.Clear();
                        for (int j = 0; j < gg.Length; j++)
                        {
                            string[] KeyValue = gg[j].Split('=');
                            DictionaryParam.Add(KeyValue[0], KeyValue[1]);
                            dis.Add(KeyValue[1]);
                        }
                        highC.Add(Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["H"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        lowC.Add(Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["L"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        openC.Add(Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["O"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        closeC.Add(Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["C"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        LablesAxis.Add(DictionaryParam["T"].ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "\n" + DictionaryParam["T"].ToString().Substring(11));

                        if (paramOption == "c")
                        //Происходит обращение к методу который отвечает за обработку инфы
                            DrawingGraphics(DictionaryParam["T"].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["C"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        else if (paramOption == "h")
                            DrawingGraphics(DictionaryParam["T"].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["H"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        else if (paramOption == "l")
                            DrawingGraphics(DictionaryParam["T"].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["L"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        else if (paramOption == "o")
                            DrawingGraphics(DictionaryParam["T"].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["O"].Replace('.', ',')));
                        if (dis[6].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            updateViewer = true;
                            viewer.updateViewPort(true, false);
                            viewer.updateViewPort(true, false);
                            crossHeairTrigger = true;
                        }

                        allCandles++;
                        allCandlesStatus.Text = "Получено свечек: " + allCandles.ToString();
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Данный метод работает во вторичном потоке, при помощи цикла while постоянно ожидаем появления файла, после появления файла считываем его и удаляем, затем распиливаем считанный файл по указанному символу и записываем в массив, затем с помощью следующего цикла перебираем полученный массив и каждую его строку сплитим по указанному символу и записываем в другой массив, после происходит снова сплит и запись в коллекцию ключей и значений. Затем раскидывал из этой коллекции с ключами и значениями по другим коллекциям, а затем происходит обращение к методу, и отправка ему параметров. 
А вот затем начинается самое интересное - обращение должно происходить мгновенно, но этого не происходит. Проходит некоторое время, прежде чем управление передается методу public static void DrawingGraphics(string nt, double prc).

Происходит такая задержка только при первой итерации цикла

```
for (int i = 0; i < ll.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                       //.....
                    }
```

Код самого метода предоставить не могу, ибо проект коммерческий, но факт в том, что после обращения из кода выше проходит некоторое время прежде чем это обращение действительно произойдет.
Такая задержка происходит только после первого обращения, дальше все хорошо. 
Пробовал обращаться из основного потока, пробовал делать обращение по нажатия кнопки, но результат не менятеся

```
public static void DrawingGraphics(string nt, double prc)
    {

    }
```

Comment: А зачем это: `Thread.Sleep(1);` ? В умных книгах пишут, что такое в продакшен коде использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

1. Установи [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), у него есть бесплатная лицензия на 10 дней, добавь после первого вызова метода принудительное завершение процесса (`Environment.Exit(1);`) и запусти его из-под `dotTrace` в режиме `Timeline`.
   В полученном отчёте ты увидишь - что именно заняло столько времени
2. Вероятнее всего, в процессе обращения к методу происходит инициализация каких-либо статичных объектов или генерация сериализаторов, которая и занимает время.
3. Не нужно писать методы на 30 000 строк - разбей их на маленькие методы, их будет удобнее поддерживать и проще читать. Методы, выполняющие определенный круг задач или законченный алгоритм выдели в отдельные классы. Это также может помочь и с твоей проблемой, но тебе должно хватить профилировщика из п.1
4. Не используй `while(true){sleep(1)}`, большую часть времени ты вхолостую гоняешь процессор, мешая ему эффективно переключаться между остальными задачами.
5. Для отслеживания появления новых файлов на файловой системе используй [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). Новые файлы помещай в очередь. Выбирая элемент из очереди, проверяй его наличие на файловой системе и права на чтение. Файла нет - удаляешь из очереди. Файл есть, но недоступен - ждёшь или переходишь к следующему. Файл доступен - начинаешь обрабатывать.
6. Не делай пустые обработчики всех возможных исключений. В процессе эксплуатации комерческого ПО может случится всё что угодно. Вынеси проверку на блокировку в отдельный метод. Набор решений [можешь найти здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use).
7. Никогда не делай так: `Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["H"].Replace('.', ',')`, если твою программу запустят на машине с европейской локалью, вызов точно так же упадёт с ошибкой форматирования. Обе стороны - и заполняющая файл и читающая его должны использовать [универсальный формат](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) хранения данных, вот так: `Double.Parse(DictionaryParam["H"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
8. Не работай с не типизированными динамическими параметрами о волшебных именах которых знаешь только ты. Задай [именованные константы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants) или [перечисление](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) для элементов `paramOption`. Вместо того чтобы хранить параметры в 4 коллекциях, опиши тип, представляющий входные данные.

Например:

```
class MyType
{
  public Double HightValue;
  public Double LowValue;
  public Double OpenValue;
  public Double CloseValue;
  ... UnknownParam4;
  ... UnknownParam5;
  ... UnknownParam6;

  public Boolean IsCrossHeairTrigger()
  {
    return UnknownParam6 == 1;
  }
}
```

Ведь намного удобнее хранить один объект, и обращаться к `obj.OpenValue` вместо того, чтобы каждый раз делать так: `Convert.ToDouble(DictionaryParam["O"].Replace('.', ',')`. Заодно прочувствуешь, насколько неприятно менять эти значения в нескольких местах, когда они стремительно расползаются по всему проекту, копируясь из одного места в другое. Опять же, вызов метода `IsCrossHeairTrigger` намного понятнее, чем условие `dis[6].ToString() == "1"` и это сейчас оно такое, а потом добавится новый аргумент, и не после, а перед, и будешь ты по всему проекту вносить правки и тратить драгоценное время.

Удачи с рефакторингом!